# MYSQL Left Join month count from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add columns that represent month base counts from other table.

I have 2 tables.

**Leave application**

```
leaveid     Userid      
1            3
2            4
3            5
4            1
```

**Leave Dates**

```
dateid    leaveid      leavedates 
1            1          2015-10-06
2            1          2015-10-07 
3            2          2015-11-01
4            2          2015-11-02
5            3          2015-01-01
6            4          2015-02-12
```

I want to end up with total leave count based on months:

```
userid    january     fabruary    march   so on...
1           1           3            1
2           2           0            1
2           3           4            1
```

Comment: What's your attempts? what you are looking for is a simple join,group by extract month from date and pivot the answer.

Comment: This is a Q/A site, so it would not hurt if you actually asked a question. Along with your question you could also share what you have tried so far!

Comment: Actually your query would be a bit involved, and your tables are very hard to read.

Comment: You can try group by userid and 12 count of each leavedates for each month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do conditional summing of the entries, something like this:-

```
SELECT a.userid,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(leavedates) = 1, 1, 0)) AS january,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(leavedates) = 2, 1, 0)) AS february,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(leavedates) = 3, 1, 0)) AS march,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(leavedates) = 4, 1, 0)) AS april,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(leavedates) = 5, 1, 0)) AS may,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(leavedates) = 6, 1, 0)) AS june,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(leavedates) = 7, 1, 0)) AS july,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(leavedates) = 8, 1, 0)) AS august,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(leavedates) = 9, 1, 0)) AS september,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(leavedates) = 10, 1, 0)) AS october,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(leavedates) = 11, 1, 0)) AS november,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(leavedates) = 12, 1, 0)) AS december
FROM Leave_application a
LEFT OUTER JOIN Leave_dates b
ON a.leaveid = b.leaveid
GROUP BY a.userid
```

Comment: I replaced LEFT OUTER JOIN with LEFT JOIN and its worked . Thanks

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN is just the full syntax for LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like as following query:-

```
SELECT  la.`userid`,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(ld.`leavedates`) = 1, 1, 0)) as january,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(ld.`leavedates`) = 2, 1, 0)) as february,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(ld.`leavedates`) = 3, 1, 0)) as march,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(ld.`leavedates`) = 4, 1, 0)) as april,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(ld.`leavedates`) = 5, 1, 0)) as may,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(ld.`leavedates`) = 6, 1, 0)) as june,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(ld.`leavedates`) = 7, 1, 0)) as july,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(ld.`leavedates`) = 8, 1, 0)) as augest,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(ld.`leavedates`) = 9, 1, 0)) as september,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(ld.`leavedates`) = 10, 1, 0)) as october,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(ld.`leavedates`) = 11, 1, 0)) as november,
        SUM(IF(MONTH(ld.`leavedates`) = 12, 1, 0)) as december
      FROM `leave_application` as la
      LEFT JOIN `leave_dates` as ld
        ON (ld.`leaveid` = la.`leaveid`)
      GROUP BY ld.`leaveid`
```

Comment: Added comma after every months and group by userid.

Comment: yes i missed out the comma after every months. but why you have to group by userid?